# How do I create a function that executes if the time is equal to x?

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I was creating a webpage and I would like to receive assistance in that. I need a text to popup when the UTCHours and UTCMinutes are equal to specific values. I want something like this. This is like the model , not actual code.

```
h = utcTime
m = utcminutes
if (h=x and m=y) 
   {
    function myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Get the current time on page load, perform math to get the duration until the desired time, set a timeout for that duration to execute the method.

Comment: In regards to the answers below, `setTimeout()` is more appropriate than `setInterval()`.  If you calculate the duration between now and the time it should run, there's no reason to check again in an interval.  You **know** how long they need to wait for the method to execute.  Running an interval creates unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Surely I wont do everything for you, but here you go. A base to start from.

```
// The button functionality
const $ = (x) => document.getElementById(x);

$('start').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    startTime();
});

$('stop').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    stopTime();
});

// The timer

// set variables
let date,
start,
stop;

function startTime() {
  date = new Date(); // get current date.
  start = date.getTime(); // get time from current date
  // Just output
  document.getElementById("showStart").innerHTML = start;
}

function stopTime() {
  date = new Date(); // get current date.
  stop = date.getTime(); // get time from current date
  // just output
  document.getElementById("showStop").innerHTML = stop;
  document.getElementById("difference").innerHTML = stop-start;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/uohqrnf8)

I was bored so here you go.

```
// The button functionality
const $ = (x) => document.getElementById(x);

$('setAlert').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    setAlert(3); // alert in x seconds.
});

// set variables
let date,
target,
stop,
interval = 1; // integer.

function setAlert(time) {
  date = new Date(); // get current date.
  target = date.getTime() + ( (time * 1000) - ((interval * 1000) +1000) ); // sets the time it should alert.
  /*
   * time -1 because it's a 1s interval, that means when it reaches x = y it will alert 1s later by the next "check". This why you need to subtract 1s.
   * (time-1)*1000 is because the getTime returns time in ms not in seconds. You would need to make it setAlert(3000),
   *         i made it bit easier by multiplying the value by 1000 = ms.
   */
  // The loop that checks time
  setInterval(function(){ // This function makes the "checking each X ms"
      if(stop !== target){ // Check if time was reached.
          stopTime(); // Check time
      }else{
          alert("TIME IS OVER"); // When time is reached do this.
      }
  }, interval*1000); // Refreshes the time each second.

  // Just output
  document.getElementById("showTarget").innerHTML = target+(interval*1000); // Because the target time has "minus" in it (line 16) it needs to be added to show the real target time.
}


function stopTime() {
  date = new Date(); // get current date.
  stop = date.getTime(); // get time from current date
  // just output
  document.getElementById("showStop").innerHTML = stop;
  // document.getElementById("difference").innerHTML = stop-target;
}
```

[jsfiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/uohqrnf8/28)

Comment: Rather than *setInterval*, why not just work out the interval to the required time and set one interval with *setTimeout*? Of course this all depends on the local host, but maybe that doesn't matter… something like: `delay = new Date().setUTCHours(h, m, 0, 0) - new Date()`. ;-)

Comment: This can be done in different ways, I will need something like this also for my website and i will do it different. More efficient :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function displayAlert(hour,minute){

   //create a new Date Object(Current Date and Time)
   var date = new Date();
   
   // getUTCHours getUTCMinutes are inbuilt methods 
   // for getting UTC hour and minute by comparing it with timezone
   var utcHour = date.getUTCHours();
   var utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
   
   //display alert when utc hour and minute matches sired time
   if(utcHour == hour && utcMinutes == minute){
        alert(utcHour + " : " + utcMinutes)
   }
}

displayAlert(18,31)
```

Comment: you can add this code inside a setInterval to check it contiuously

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function(){
now = new Date();
hours = now.getUTCHours();
mins = now.getUTCMinutes();
executeFunctionIfEqualToDefined(hours, mins);
},60000); // this block will run every 60000 milli seconds i.e 60 seconds =1 min


function executeFunctionIfEqualToDefined(hours, mins){
  if(hours === x && mins === y){
    //execute your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Downvoters plz add comments why? Its like we spend our time on solution and producing answers but simply someone downvotes

Comment: Your post has just appeared in the `Low Quality Posts` [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22000963). The reason for this (and *probably* the reason why someone downvoted your answer) is that your post contains code with no explanation of how it works and/or how it solves OPs problem.

Comment: It also has syntax and logic errors and one of the two comment statements is wrong.

Comment: I did edit my answer and hope this time i marked the comment statements correct. Thanks for notifying